# задача на комбинаторику

Tags: javascript, java, c#, комбинаторика

Решил упростить себе работу и переложить часть рутинных расчетов на программу, но простая, на первый взгляд, задача не поддается решению. Может кто-нибудь подскажет.

Есть ArrayList со случайным количеством элементов. Есть параметр **int max**. Все элементы в массиве уже гарантированно меньше  int max.
Для примера. int max=10; Ну и числа в листе(2,7,9,1,3,5,4,7,1,2,3);
Нужно скомбинировать эти отрезки в группы, чтобы сумма группы была<=int max. И вывести суммы чисел этих групп.

```
Например
1,5,3=9;
1,4,4=9;
1,2,1,3=7;
```

Т.е. если сравнивать **int max** с коробкой а числа в листе с вещами, то нужно распихать всякий хлам в коробки максимально компактно и вывести результат. 
 Можно java,c#,js или что-нибудь другое понятное; Если кому интересно, то отрезки - это куски труб. если есть например 3,4,5,2-х метровые куски, то нужно заказать 9 метровый кусок и 5-и метровый. Т.к. максимальная длина -10м.

Comment: Если Вам не важен язык программирования (нужен не код, а описание алгоритма), то поставьте метки [любой-язык] и [алгоритм]. Если нужен какой-то конкретный, то оставьте его, а остальные уберите (сейчас стоят сразу `javascript`, `java` и `C#`)

Comment: По задаче уточните: достаточно найти любой набор групп, минимальный или нужно найти все возможные? Если пробовали реализовать укажите точно что вызывает затруднения.

Comment: Одномерная задача раскроя. И не надо велосипед изобретать...

Comment: [Задача о ранце](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Задача_о_ранце), [Задача раскроя](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Задача_раскроя).

Comment: Я написал решение для задачи раскроя, хоть у меня и отличается немного условие - меньше переменных, но время выполнения становится слишком долгим при большом количестве переменных. Нужно какое-то примерное решение без полного перебора вариантов.

Answer (score 0):

Есть такой вариант но он кривой довольно

```
namespace FileRead
{
    class Program
    {
        static List<List<int>> result = new List<List<int>>();
        static int max = 10;
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {


            List<int> l = new List<int>();
            Random rnd = new Random();
            for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++)
            {
                l.Add(rnd.Next(max));
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Исходный массив");
            foreach (var item in l)
            {
                Console.Write($"{item} ");
            }
            Console.WriteLine("\n");
            Calc(l);
            Console.WriteLine("\n\n\n");

            foreach (var item in result)
            {
                foreach (var item1 in item)
                {
                    Console.Write(item1);
                }
                Console.WriteLine();
            }

            Console.Read();

        }

        static void Calc(List<int> list)
        {
            if (list.Count <= 2)
                return;
            var t = new List<int>();
            var e = list.TakeWhile(g => { t.Add(g); return t.Sum() < max; }).ToList();
            result.Add(e.ToList());
            for (int i = 0; i < e.Count; i++)
            {
                list.Remove(e[i]);
            }
            Calc(list);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Проблема актуальна. Методом полного перебора решить задачу не получается. При количестве отрезков больше 10-15 время выполнения становится слишком большим.